# Fastest way to find current file for alias

Tags: macos, bash, shell, alias, zsh

Normaly e.g. `alias ll="ls -la"`
is stored in `~/.bashrc` (or ~/.bash_profile).

But what ist the most effective way to find the location where is an alias stored?
I come across this question, because alias `la` runs perfect, but it's not stored in
the usual suspected locations.(~/.bashrc)

How can I find out where is an alias located?

`echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh`

And yes, I know for zsh is `.zshrc` the usual suspect.

Comment: Are you using a **dotfile** config ?

Comment: `.bashrc` isn't used by `zsh`, so there's no point looking there if you are using `zsh`. That aside, no shell I'm aware of tracks which file an alias was defined from. The best you can do is understand what files a shell will read automatically on startup, and check those first, following any references to other files (`source` or `.`) that may be executed.

Comment: Yes I know, but the "find" problem ist the same in BASH.
I am looking for this command: 
```show me the location/file where "la" is stored/located```

Comment: You can use type command to determine first whether that is a alias or not and then you can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The alias you create on the command prompt will be valid only till the current session. Once you exit the session and re-login, it will not be preserved. So it is upto you where to store it depending on its usage. e.g. for login specific, you can store it in /etc/profile. If you want it sourced during non-login session, the use .bashrc, if you want it to be sourced always, then use bash_profile. I am assuming bash shell. Reference - http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/147054-where-alias-stored.html

So I guess the answer is that it is really upto you to manually store it. Just because you define it on the command line, will not get it stored automatically.

Comment: That is not what the OP is asking. The question is: how is it possible to find out in which file an alias is defined?

Comment: OK :). Then @Teletubbi-osx, you can try running grep on the regular suspects or on the directories e.g. grep 'alias' ~/.bashrc /etc/profile/ ~/bash_profile.